# Time varying random variable

Tags: time-series, variance, mean

I am studying the water surface elevation in the presence of waves, at one location over time $\eta(t)$ as seen in the following figure.

[image]

The value of $\eta$ at this location at one time moment e.g. $\eta(t_1)$ is a random variable because if we repeat this experiment under statistically identical conditions we will get different value each time, see figure below.

[image]

So, $\eta(t)$ is varying over time and from realization to another. Suppose I want to calculate the average and variance of the surface elevation, should I do double averaging, i.e. time averaging then ensemble averaging? or vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

$\eta(t)$ is a random process, its value at each time instant is a random variable, e.g. $\eta(t_1), \eta(t_2)$ etc. are all random variables. And, in general, they're *different* random variables. When you calculate the expected value for each of these variables, you get the *mean process*, i.e. combine $\mu_{\eta}(t_i)=E[\eta(t_i)]$ into $E[\eta(t)]=\mu_{\eta}(t)$, which is another random process.

In general, an estimation for the mean process is obtained via averaging across the process' realizations, not time-averaging across one realization, which gives . you only one value. When the process is assumed to be *constant mean* because it is *stationary* (or wide-sense stationary - WSS), or for some other reason, $\mu(t)=\mu$. When the process is [mean-ergodic](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Ergodic_process), you approach $\mu$ if you take the time average of *one* sufficiently long realization, which saves you from creating several realizations. Of course, this is the theoretical aspect. In real world problems, you have to really know it or assume it (i.e. ergodicity, stationarity etc.).

For the average *surface elevation*, you actually need to specify which average you're talking about before making any calculations and know what you get. If your process is constant mean and mean-ergodic, you'll get an accurate representation of $\hat{\mu}$ when you double average, or just take one long realization and apply just time-averaging. When you don't have constant mean, first obtain the mean process from realizations, and then decide if you really want to see the time-average of it.

Discussion follows similarly for $\sigma^2$ (stationarity, ergodicity etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helps. It turns out that stationarity and ergodicity assumptions are essential (and legit) in this analysis. I have one more question. Suppose I want to use the Fourier transform to do spectral analysis for the time record. So, if the process is ergodic, is it valid to assume that each harmonic component is ergodic?